# Trouble with overriding a variable in abstract class

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala and have the following question about overriding a variable in an abstract class.

```
abstract class ExampleClass1 {
    val testVar = (i: String) => {
        i + " A"
    }

    def exampleMethod1() = {
        print testVar
    }
}

object ExampleObject1 extends ExampleClass1 {
    def getExampleValue() = {
        exampleMethod1()
    }
}
```

ExampleClass1 and ExampleObject1 are in one module. My module is calling `ExampleObject1.getExampleValue`. I want to change the behavior of testVar in ExampleClass1. Is it possible to do this without changing ExampleObjectt1?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with "my module is calling ExampleObject1"? There's no such thing as "calling an object". You can call methods in an object, but you can't call an object itself.

Comment: Ah I understand. I realized I missed the calling method. Updated Code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a value after the class is instantiated, then you should use `var` instead of `val`, but without any further information it seems that there is a flaw in your design.

If you want to set the value of the given string on object creation, you can use something like this:

```
scala> abstract class ExampleClass1(val i: String)
defined class ExampleClass1
scala> object ExampleObject1 extends ExampleClass1("A")
defined object ExampleObject1
scala> ExampleObject1.i
res1: String = A
```

Or if you want to use given string as a parameter:

```
scala> abstract class ExampleClass2 {
 | def test(i: String) = i + " A"
 | }
defined class ExampleClass2
scala> object ExampleObject2 extends ExampleClass2
defined object ExampleObject2
scala> ExampleObject2.test("B")
res2: String = B A
```

What is your goal?

Comment: my goal is to define a new value for 'def test' in an extended class (override test variable). My design may not be right to do the override but wanted to check if scala has underlying magic to do this.

Comment: Like this (for the second example in my comment): `object ExampleObject3 extends ExampleClass2 { override def test(i: String) = i + " C" }` ?